# JQuery select list item

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to select an item from a list once it is clicked; I've tried appending classes and things like that but the click event doesn't seem to recognise the list items, the items also need be able to be deleted later so I think giving them classes is the best option for this scenario here is my code:

```js
function newElement() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#UL").append($("<li>").html($("input").val()).addClass("Item"));
  });

};

$(".item").click(function() {
  var $items = $('li'),
    $selected = $items.filter('.selected').removeClass('selected'),
    $next;
  // first time only when no selected exists, remove if you automatically select first one
  if (!$selected.length) {
    $next = $items.first();
  } else {
    $next = $selected.is($items.last()) ? $items.first() : $selected.next();
  }

  $next.addClass('selected')

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1" class="header">
  <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="...">
  <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
</div>

<ul id="UL" class="nyList">
  <li class="item">blank 1</li>
  <li class="item">blank 2</li>
  <li class="item">blank 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So, you need to be able to view the entire list; click on an item and it does something?

Comment: Please update your question with more details for clarity of what you need OR select one of the answers that best answers your question.  Note I outlined where you have a number of challenges in the code presented here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70336691/125981

Answer (score 1):

If i understood your question that the next `<li>` must get the selected class.

Then its achievable using your code with slight changes.

Fist add a `data-key`

```
<ul id="UL" class="nyList">
    <li data-key='0' class="item">blank 1</li>
    <li data-key='1' class="item">blank 2</li>
    <li data-key='2' class="item">blank 3</li>
</ul>
```

Then use that marker for the click event

```
$(".item").click(function() {
    var $items = $('li'), $next;
    var target = $(this).data('key') + 1 ;
    $items.removeClass('selected')
    if (target >= $items.length) {
        $next = $items[0];
    } else {
        $next = $items[target];
    }
    $next.classList.add('selected');
});
```

Comment: I was going to suggest `$('#nyList').children();` but yours is more elegant

Comment: why do `$selected = `  since you never use it? just put the `$items.removeClass('selected');` after you declare your variables

Answer (score 0):

If your question is that how to add list item dynamically and assign an eventHandler for click on them, you can do it like this: (in below example I just toggle the selected class)

```js
function newElement() {
  $("#UL").append($("<li>").html($("input").val()).addClass("item"));
};

$('#UL').on('click', '.item', function() {
  const target = $(this);
  const shouldSelect = !target.hasClass('selected');

  $('#UL li.selected').removeClass('selected');
  shouldSelect && target.addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1" class="header">
  <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="...">
  <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
</div>
<ul id="UL" class="nyList">
  <li class="item">blank 1</li>
  <li class="item">blank 2</li>
  <li class="item">blank 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$('#UL li.selected')` would perhaps be better as `$(this).find('.selected'))`

Comment: `$(this)` will be `li` item which has clicked.

Comment: Ah yes, on second glance I see you scoped the class in the event instantiation with `.item` so just `$(eventDelegate).find('.selected')` from `function(event)` then - no need to repeat the ID part.  OR alternately `$(this).siblings('.selected')` - BUT the OP was somewhat unclear on the actual need/use of the "select" so you might be correct in this  also...

Answer (score 0):

Your question was slightly unclear regarding the "select" statement thus, I made an assumption you wanted to do something with a selected element - like remove it; so I added an example of that functionality.

### Some comments regarding code and changes I suggest:

- Did not need to put the append inside a document ready event handler in a function - this was essentially adding a new event handler that would never fire since that event has already been triggered.
- Used the wrong class in one place `Item` vs `item` in `.addClass("Item"));` JavaScript when using a class value are case sensitive
- I cloned the first `.item` `li` when we start here to use in case all the `li` get deleted, otherwise I clone the first one when you "add" to allow more modular code - if you end up with more "inside" your `li` for example a span or some such - easier to "modify it" than "create it there with complex markup addition(s). Example  `<li class="item"><span class="ml-1">blank</span> 1</li>`
- using 'UL' or other tag names as a id selector is not a great choice so I gave the `ul` an id instead `<ul id="my-ul-list"`
- cached the `$myList` to make a refactor easier for that new ul with an id
- added a button to trigger a delete of the selected `li` mentioned in your question - you can refactor from that if needed.

```js
// save a cloned item to add when we remove them all
let clonedItemSave = $('#my-ul-list').find('.item').first().clone(true, true);
let $myList = $('#my-ul-list');

function newElement(event) {
  let clonedItem =
    (!!$myList.find('.item').length) ?
    $myList.find('.item').first().clone(true, true) : clonedItemSave;
  let addInput = $("#add-item-input").val();
  //insert new clone of item if we have an input value:
  if (addInput != "") {
    clonedItem.html($("input").val()).appendTo("#my-ul-list");
  }
}
// scope to the UL since any might be removed later per question statement
// gave the ul an id so we can target it specifically
$myList.on('click', '.item', function(event) {
    // delegateTarget is the UL here
    let $items = $(event.delegateTarget).find('li');
    $items.filter('.selected').not(this).removeClass('selected');
    $selected = $items.filter('.selected').not(this).removeClass('selected');
    $selected = $('.selected');
    if (!!$selected.length) {
      $selected.toggleClass("selected")
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
  })
  // handle the remove
  .on('remove-selected', function() {
    $(this).find('.selected').remove();
  });
$('#add-button').on('click', newElement);
$('#remove-selected').on('click', function(even) {
  //trigger the remove
  $myList.trigger('remove-selected');
});
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: #ffff00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <input type="text" id="add-item-input" placeholder="...">
  <button type="button" class="addBtn" id="add-button">Add</button>
</div>

<ul id="my-ul-list" class="nyList">
  <li class="item">blank 1</li>
  <li class="item">blank 2</li>
  <li class="item">blank 3</li>
</ul>
<button type="button" id="remove-selected">Remove Selected</button>
```